# Unable to understand how the program is being executed

Tags: java, if-statement

[image]I saw an question paper of NET examination and found the following java question

```
public class First {

  public static int CBSE(int x) {
    if (x < 100) x = CBSE(x + 10);
    return (x - 1);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(First.CBSE(60));
  }
}
```

I am unable to understand the if condition. I ran the program on my machine and it returns 95 without any error. Can anyone please demonstrate how the program is executed?

Comment: What is `int CBSE(int 10)` supposed to be? That aside: I'm not 100* sure I understand the question--the `if` statement is `x < 100` meaning the associated statement will run if `x` is less than `100`. I *suspect* your confusion is recursion, not `if`.

Comment: To that end: play computer w/ pen and paper. Plug in a value. Write down the steps the code is taking and what `CBSE` returns, and *when* that value is returned.

Comment: @DaveNewton please check the question again, I have corrected it

Comment: The question is the same except now there's a giant picture. `if (x < 100)` it will set `x` to the result of calling `CBSE` (recursion) until `CBSE` is entered with x >= 100. Unless you step through the code, or play computer w/ pen and paper, or drop logging statements on entry to `CBSE`, in the `if` condition`, and immediately prior to return, it won't "click". This is the nature of recursion. (It's also handy to include an indentation level to show "where you are" in the recursion, and it's often easier to just trace the execution on paper.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 10 on the second line is x

```
CBSE(60)
=CBSE(70)-1
=CBSE(80)-1-1
=CBSE(90)-1-1-1
=CBSE(100)-1-1-1-1
=99-1-1-1-1
=95
```

Comment: yes I get it, but how the program is executed in the if statement, can you explain?

Comment: I assume you call the "if statement" the code executed when the condition is true.

The only if statement is `x = CBSE(x + 10)`.

The first step is to calculate `x + 10`.
The second step is to call the function CBSE with this value.
The third step is to put the result in the `x` variable.

Please note, that each call to CBSE has its own context, in other words each has its own `x` variable.

Answer (score 0):

CBSE(60) ->

```
             60<100 so, x=CBSE(70)

                   ...................................80

                                       ............................................90

                                              ......................................................100    

                                                                                 100  is not < 100  SO CBSE(100) Returns 100-1=99

        cbse(90) returns 98

  cbse(80) returns 97
```

cbse(70)returns 96

cbse(60) returns 95

therefore the final result is 95

Answer (score 0):

You use a recursive function.
Any new call is stacked while x<100.
If you put trace inside BSE function you will see :

```
entering CBSE with 60
entering CBSE with 70
entering CBSE with 80
entering CBSE with 90
entering CBSE with 100
exiting CBS with 99
exiting CBS with 98
exiting CBS with 97
exiting CBS with 96
exiting CBS with 95
95
```